# how to insertAfter html element with jquery in certain window size

Tags: jquery, resize, insertafter

I intend to restructure html element with jquery in certain window size. But I have problem when it run else statement, it's keep inserting element How to prevent else statement to run only once.

```js
$(window).on("resize", function(){
  var width = $(this).width();
  windowSize(width);
});

function windowSize(wSize){
  if ($(window).width() < 767) {
    $('.text').insertAfter('.box');
  }
  else {
    $('.text').prependTo('.box');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <p class="text">test</p>
  <ul class="order">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="text">test</p>
  <ul class="order">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <p class="text">test</p>
  <ul class="order">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery documentation for prependTo():

> A selector, element, HTML string, array of elements, or jQuery object;
>   the matched set of elements will be inserted at the beginning of the
>   element(s) specified by this parameter.

Else statement will run anytime you resize the window and window width is lower than 767. You got me?

Also,  `if ($(window).width() < 767) {` can be replaced with  `if (wSize < 767) {`

What exactly do you want to achieve here? How would you like to have the html?

Comment: I want to move .text and insert after .box when window <767, and .text back to .box again when window >767